# Difference between seen vs saw

Tags: tense, past-tense

I'm a little bit confused. I know that *seen* is the past participle of *see*, and that *saw* is the past simple. I know also that we use the past participle with the perfect tense.

In my case, I want to talk about an action in the past and so I **feel** the right sentence is:

> .....the one seen at the beginning is ....

However, since I'm talking about a past action, I **think** that the right sentence may be:

> .....the one saw at the beginning is ....

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: it's irregular: I see, I saw, I have seen. The one seen at the beginning. The past participle is SEEN, not saw. But here, it's a passive tense: the one seen at the beginning [of the x by y]. Passives take the past participle. The agent of the passive verb: /seen at the beginning/ is implied. Saw can only be used with a pronoun or noun: We saw the boat in the harbor.

Comment: As long as you use *is* you can't talk about an action in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English there are two different *voices* that may be employed when making a statement: *active voice* and *passive voice*.

In the active voice the subject of the sentence is also the *agent* in the sentence; the subject performs the verb's action on the *patient*.

In the passive voice the *patient* becomes the subject of the sentence, getting acted on by the verb. A sentence in the passive voice uses the auxiliary verb *be* to indicate the tense and the main verb always becomes the past participle.

In your extract, *the one* is not the agent (the one *doing the seeing*), but is the patient (the one that *is seen*), so it is in the passive voice and uses the past participle form of the verb see. I.e. the first extract is the correct one:

> .....the one seen at the beginning is ....